# Head and basename together gives terminated by signal 13

Tags: linux, find

How do I get rid of `find: basename terminated by signal 13`? I've tried moving stuff around, finding an alternative to `head -1`, but I cannot figure it out.

```
david@server:/hdd_1/handbrake/log$ plex="/hdd_1/plex" && find "$plex" -type f -iname "*.mkv" -exec basename {} \; | head -1
Predestination (2014).mkv
find: `basename' terminated by signal 13
find: `basename' terminated by signal 13
find: `basename' terminated by signal 13
find: `basename' terminated by signal 13
find: `basename' terminated by signal 13
find: `basename' terminated by signal 13
find: `basename' terminated by signal 13
find: `basename' terminated by signal 13
find: `basename' terminated by signal 13
find: `basename' terminated by signal 13
```

Comment: See [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/26462/60101). A pipe re-directs stdout from one command to the stdin of another command, but `head` has already exited so `basename` continuing to attempt to write output leads to a broken pipe. You may want to check the `exit` codes of basename, but assuming it always returns `true`, just appending `-quit`, instead of piping to `head -n1` should solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Signal 13 means "broken pipe". `head` has already got what it needs and ended, but `basename` is still pumping into the pipe (which is now leading nowhere, thus signal 13).

Try this one:

```
plex="/hdd_1/plex" && find "$plex" -type f -iname "*.mkv" | head -1 | xargs basename
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably has something to do with spaces.

Try this:

```
plex="/hdd_1/plex" && find "$plex" -type f -iname "*.mkv" -print0 | xargs -0 basename | head -1
```

Comment: basename: extra operand ‘/hdd_1/plex/movie/Earth to Echo (2014).mkv’